# $E_\infty$ spectrum corresponding to $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, derived-categories

First of the questions about derived algebraic geometry from a noobie.

The way I understand it, every discrete ring $R$ corresponds to some ring spectrum whose $\pi_0$ is $R$. Now consider $p$-adic numbers. They are a limit of discrete rings — what should correspond to them? How to generalize?

(+ what could be good tags for derived algebraic geometry? I was considering: e-infinity, infty-structures, math-0703204, derived-alggeom, derived-spaces, infty-topology, a-infinity-algebras (2 currently tagged))

Comment: The word "spectrum" doesn't need infinity attached to it.  Also, I recommend "derived-stuff"

Comment: (Simpsons quote: *Garbage goes to the garbage bin... Makes sense.*) Derived-stuff it is.

Comment: The E_\infty says that it has a highly structured multiplication lifting the multiplication on R - properly it's an E_\infty ring spectrum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is indeed an Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $H\Bbb Z_p$.  It is equivalent to the $p$-completion of $H\Bbb Z$ and the (homotopy) limit of the $H\Bbb Z/p^k$.  However, it doesn't remember the topology.

If you want to remember the topology on the p-adics you need to do something more complicated, such as view the inverse system $\{H\Bbb Z/p^k\}$ as a pro-object in spectra rather than actually taking the limit.  This is something like what you would do if you wanted to talk about formal schemes.

Answer (score 10):

I would argue that looking for a ring spectrum is not the right thing to do.  What you should be looking for is the category of modules over that possibly non-existent ring spectrum, as an infinity-category or just as a triangulated category.  If you think about it this way, an obvious answer presents itself.

Begin with the category of $H\Bbb Z$-modules, or the derived category of $\Bbb Z$, or its infinity-category version.  Now take the Bousfield localization with respect to the object $Fp$ (thought of as a complex in degree $0$).  This is not a smashing localization, so this category is not equivalent to modules over $H\Bbb Z_p$ .  As a triangulated category, it is compactly generated, but by $Fp$ itself.  The sphere is not small.  So this category is equivalent to modules over a DGA, the endomorphism DGA of $Fp$, but it is not commutative.  It is more like a DG Hopf algebra, I suspect, so that its homotopy category has a tensor product even though it is not commutative.  I have always thought this example needs more investigation, though it might be in Dwyer-Greenlees-Iyengar somewhere.  It is a toy version of the $K(n)$-local stable homotopy category.

Mark

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this actually helps answer your question, but [Gereon Quick](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/gquick/) has done some work on profinite simplicial objects that may be relevant.  You might want to poke around his papers a bit.

Answer (score 2):

There is a perfectly functional Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $H\Bbb Z_p$, although it returns the discrete ring.  It looks like you want a way to attach spectra to cohomology theories with topologized coefficient groups, and I don't know if that's possible (in particular the wedge axiom in Brown representability smells funny).

Random ideas that may or may not work:

- Take a limit of Eilenberg-Maclane spectra $H\Bbb Z/p^n$
- Take a $p$-completion of $H\Bbb Z$

Comment: @Daniele, editing ten old questions in quick succession bumps ten newer questions off the front page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for pointing this out. Also Yemon Choi in [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450111/inverse-of-bochner-martinelli-formula/450154#comment1163550_450154) warned me, so I stopped and read a couple of relevant meta post as suggested by him.